# How to form an unique collection with one element taken from each array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Say I have 3 integer arrays: `{1,2,3},  {2,3},  {1}`

I must take exactly one element from each array, to form a new array where all numbers are unique. In this example, the correct answers are: `{2,3,1} and {3,2,1}`. (Since I must take one element from the 3rd array, and I want all numbers to be unique, I must never take the number 1 from the first array.)

What I have done:

```
for a in array1:
    for b in array2:
        for c in array3:
            if a != b and a != c and b != c:
                AddAnswer(a,b,c)
```

This is brute force, which works, but it doesn't scale well. What if now we are dealing with 20 arrays instead of just 3. I don't think it's good to write a 20 nested for-loops. Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: Do you need all the possible sets or just one?

Comment: All the possible sets, thank you.

Comment: So much easier when you specify a language. :)

Comment: One option is to do a recursive function that lists all the solutions from a list of sets when you exclude a list of values: if there is one set, you just return the list of remaining values (in a singleton set), otherwise you loop on the remaining values of the first set and you recurse adding the current value to the excluded list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
import itertools

arrs = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [1]]

for x in itertools.product(*arrs):
    if len(set(x)) < len(arrs): continue
    AddAnswer(x)
```

`AddAnswer(x)` is called twice, with the tuples:

```
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: You can make it more generic by changing it to `if len(set(x)) < len(arrs)`

Comment: Obligatory note to my own answer: this is still brute force.

Comment: Is the same possible with sets?

Comment: @allcaps, do you mean, for example: `arrs = [set([1,2,3]), set([2,3]), set([1])]` -- if so then yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of this as finding a matching in a bipartite graph.

You are trying to select one element from each set, but are not allowed to select the same element twice, so you are trying to match sets to numbers.

You can use the [matching function in the graph library NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html) to do this efficiently.

Python example code:

```
import networkx as nx

A=[ [1,2,3],  [2,3],  [1] ]

numbers = set()
for s in A:
    for n in s:
        numbers.add(n)

B = nx.Graph()
for n in numbers:
    B.add_node('%d'%n,bipartite=1)
for i,s in enumerate(A):
    set_name = 's%d'%i
    B.add_node(set_name,bipartite=0)
    for n in s:
        B.add_edge(set_name,n)

matching = nx.maximal_matching(B)
if len(matching) != len(A):
    print 'No complete matching'
else:
    for number,set_name in matching:
        print 'choose',number,'from',set_name
```

This is a simple, efficient method for finding a single matching.

If you want to enumerate through all matchings you may wish to read:
[Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and
Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs by Takeaki UNO](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which gives O(V) complexity per matching.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights. I never thought of it that way!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution (not tested):

```
def max_sets(list_of_sets, excluded=[]):
    if not list_of_sets:
        return [set()]
    else:
        res = []
        for x in list_of_sets[0]:
            if x not in excluded:
                for candidate in max_sets(list_of_sets[1:], exclude+[x]):
                    candidate.add(x)
                    res.append(candidate)
        return res
```

(You could probably dispense with the `set` but it's not clear if it was in the question or not...)